# Codeigniter - loop form input with foreach

Tags: php, codeigniter, loops, foreach

I wanted to ask how to make the code can loop the input while also able to call the database to the input(i wanted to make the value by using the database)

**View.php**

```
<?php
$i=1;
while ($i<=10){
foreach($tampilan as $u){
    ?>
    <form action="admin/guru_proses" method="POST">
    <table>
        <?php
    echo '
            <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="id_guru" value="<?php echo $u->id_guru?>"</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="nama_guru"></td>
            </tr>
     ';
    ?>

        <?php
    $i=$i+1;
}}
?>
<tr><td>
    <input type="submit">
</td></tr>
</table>
        </form>
```

The `<?php echo $u->id_guru?>` didn't seem to be working well,
it becomes like this when you open it

[the picture of the view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwAqn.png)

Comment: You're already in php echo block try value="'.$u->id_gurue.'"

Comment: Welcome. You're already in PHP, no need to `<? ?>`, use `value="' . $u->id_guru . '"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your single quotes to double quotes which you are using for echo.PHP always parse single quotes as string litrel to use the variable inside the string always use double quotes and you cannot use the php tag inside a php tag. try this

```
<?php
$i=1;
while ($i<=10){
foreach($tampilan as $u){
    ?>
    <form action="admin/guru_proses" method="POST">
    <table>
        <?php
    echo "
            <tr>
            <td><input type='text' name='id_guru' value=$u->id_guru</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='nama_guru'></td>
            </tr>
     ";
    ?>

        <?php
    $i=$i+1;
}}
?>
<tr><td>
    <input type="submit">
</td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not use php tag inside the php tag.

Please replace below line

```
<td><input type="text" name="id_guru" value="<?php echo $u->id_guru?>"</td>
```

To

```
<td><input type="text" name="id_guru" value="'.$u->id_guru.'"></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

The second php tag is being used as a simple string. I would change this whole thing into something more readable.

```
<?php $i=1; ?>
<?php while ($i<=10): ?>
    <?php foreach($tampilan as $u): ?>
    <form action="admin/guru_proses" method="POST">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" name="id_guru" value="<?php echo $u->id_guru?>"</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="nama_guru"></td>
            </tr>
        <?php $i++ ?>;
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="submit">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: well it did work and get the database but there is the  ;  in each of the input for some reason, and isn't it better when you just use bracket instead of using endforeach?

Comment: I think using {} when displaying html can get really messy real quick because it will be a lot harder to know what that bracket is actually closing.